# Problem on character formatting for import QIF Format to Microsoft Money

Tags: javascript, node.js, quicken, qif

I have problem import QIF format that have non-ascii characters to Microsoft Money..

i have this ًQIF file that create simply with Notepad++ and when import this file to Microsoft Money.. non-aschii character ( here in line start with P ) not show correctly on Microsoft Money ( showed ???? instead of محسن )

```
!Type:Cash
D3/7/2014
T-213.39
Pمحسن
N123
LGroceries
Mthis is a memo
^
D3/6/2014
T-8.16
PStarbucks
N456
LDining Out:Coffee
^
```

I try and change file format to `UTF-8 Bom` ..but not work ...
What can i do?

**Update:**
This code generated manually, but file saved by library named `qif`

```
var transactions = {
cash: [
  {
    date: '3/7/2014',
    amount: -213.39,
    payee: 'محسن',
    memo: 'this is a memo', 
    category: 'Groceries',
    checknumber: 123
  }, 
  {
    date: '3/6/2014',
    amount: -8.16,
    payee: 'Starbucks',
    category: 'Dining Out:Coffee',
    checknumber: 456
  }
]
};

var qif = require('qif');
//var qifData = qif.write(transactions);
qif.writeToFile(transactions, './out.qif', function (err, qifData) {});
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript/Node.js code here?

Comment: @HereticMonkey edited

Comment: I can see that this is copied almost verbatim from https://www.npmjs.com/package/qif... Can you open the resulting file in Quicken? I would suggest trying that. You might also file an issue on [that library's GitHub](https://github.com/jritsema/qif), although it appears as though there's been no updates done for 5 years.